# Covert int-jms:publish-subscribe-channel to spring-integration dsl

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to convert

```
<int-jms:publish-subscribe-channel id="partsPubSubChannel" topic-name="part.topic" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
```

to spring-integration dsl, this is what I have so far.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow partsPublishSubscribe() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.publishSubscribeChannel(jmsConnectionFactory)).get();
}
```

How do I set the `topic-name` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pubSubFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.publishSubscribeChannel(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                                    .destination("part.topic"))
                            .handle(...)
                             ...
                            .get();
}
```

Comment: Hi Garry, I did actually try that originally but it didn't work.  I got  the following error `The 'IntegrationFlow' can't consist of only one 'MessageChannel'. Add at lest '.bridge()' EIP-method before the end of flow.`

Comment: Right. You need to do something with the message. You can just add `.channel(...)` and the framework will bridge them. But you can't have a flow with just a channel.

Comment: I publish to this topic and subscribers get the message by simply subscribing to the topic.  I didn't need to do anything else in the XML version.  How do I replicate this in DSL?

Comment: It's a limitation of the DSL. One alternative is to simply wire it up as a @Bean. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jms/SubscribableJmsChannel.java

Comment: mmm. don't follow is it not already a bean with the @Bean annotation?  Or do you mean returning Jms.publishSubscribeChannel instead of an IntegrationFlow?

Comment: Correct. A flow can't be just a channel.

Comment: Yes it is now working now: `@Bean
    public AbstractJmsChannel partsPublishSubscribe() {
        return Jms.publishSubscribeChannel(jmsConnectionFactory)
                .destination(Topic.PART.name()).get();
    }`